# Why does PowerShell script sends email for each individual uptime server

Tags: powershell

Hello I just started to learn PowerShell and I have a script where I am trying to send a email of server uptimes. I got it to work. but it sends a email for each server uptime. So I end up with 30+ emails.  How do I consolidate that into one email below I have the script that I have tried.

```
$servers =Get-Content C:\server\hyperv1.txt
$currentdate = Get-Date
$output = write-output  "$server Uptime : $($uptime.Days) Days, $($uptime.Hours) Hours, $($uptime.Minutes) Minutes"
foreach($server in $servers){
$Bootuptime = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server).LastBootUpTime
   $uptime = $currentdate - $Bootuptime
   If (Write-output "$server Uptime : $($uptime.Days) Days, $($uptime.Hours) Hours, $($uptime.Minutes) Minutes")
   {
    $EmailFrom = “xxxxxxxxxxx”
    $EmailTo = “xxxxxxxxxxxx”
    $Subject = “Test email”
    $Body = $output
    $SMTPServer = “smtp.office365.com”
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“xxxxxxxxx”, “xxxxxxxxxx”);
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Comment: It's because you are using a "foreach", which means "for each server send this email". You need to change it so that it assembles the uptimes into a single string or list of strings. And then at the end just send an email once. It also doesn't make sense to use `write-output` in an `if` statement, so I would correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to start with an empty `$output` variable:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\server\hyperv1.txt
$output = ""
```

Then iterate through your server list, calculating the uptimes for each and appending the result to the `$output` variable (plus a newline):

```
$servers | ForEach-Object {
  $os = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_
  $uptime = (Get-Date) - $os.LastBootUpTime
  $output += "$_ Uptime : $($uptime.Days) Days, $($uptime.Hours) Hours, $($uptime.Minutes) Minutes`n"
}
```

Then, send a single email with your complete `$output`:

```
if ($output) {
  $EmailFrom = “xxxxxxxxxxx”
  $EmailTo = “xxxxxxxxxxxx”
  $Subject = “Test email”
  $Body = $output
  $SMTPServer = “smtp.office365.com”
  $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
  $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
  $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“xxxxxxxxx”, “xxxxxxxxxx”)
  $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to get the script in a single email, but the issue I am having now that its only pulling the last server in the text file. Also it is giving the error below.      Cannot find an overload for `"op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:5 char:5
+     $uptime = (Get-Date) - $os.LastBootUpTime
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest `

Comment: Sounds a bit like your `Get-CimInstance` command is not succeeding. You can make your script stop immediately and output the error by adding `-ErrorAction Stop`. So the full line would be:
`$os = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop`